# Empty user search returns entire database

Tags: python, mysql, json, mysql-python

**Context**

I've written a python script designed to run on a server. The script accepts a user input to make a search. I.E the user types in an arbitrary string and the database returns all usernames with a similar string.

**Description of problem**

I'm very uncertain about the security of the input. The program uses a stored procedure and a parameterised procedure, but despite this, if a user types in nothing i.e a blank string or if they enter something like % then the script returns every single username in the database.

**Code**

```
import json 
import mysql.connector 

class json_read():
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name  
    def json_caller(self):
            with open(self.name) as f:
                f = json.load(f)[0]
                return f

f = json_read("database_connect.json") 
config = f.json_caller()

def mysql_connect(func):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        try: 
            cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**config)
            cursor = cnx.cursor() 
            cursor.execute(*args, **kwargs)
            result = cursor.fetchall() 
            print("\nConnection is stable @ " + func.__name__)
            print(result)
        except:
            print("\nConnection failed @ " + func.__name__)
    return wrapper 

class query_dbh():
    f2 = json_read("queries.json")
    def __init__(self, index): 
        self.index = self.f2.json_caller()[index]

@mysql_connect
def query(*args, **kwargs):
    pass 

search_query = query_dbh("Search_uid").index
search_param = [raw_input("Search: ") + "%"]
query(search_query,(search_param))
```

*Queries are kept in a JSON file and loaded by the script*

```
[
    {
        "Select_names" : "SELECT first,last FROM user",
        "Select_id" : "SELECT id FROM user",
        "Order_names" : "SELECT first, last FROM user ORDER BY first ASC",
        "Search_uid" : "SELECT uid FROM user WHERE uid LIKE %s"
}
]
```

Where Search_uid is the query being used.

Comment: Why are you using `LIKE` instead of `=` ?

Comment: Good point. Thanks.

Comment: What is your qusestion? How do you want the program to behave? Why don't you just make it behave that way?